# Google calendar doesn't sync

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I use google calendar and one of my calendars within google calendar does not sync to my android phone. The calendar shows in google calendar, and syncs correctly with my desktop software (Fantastical for Mac). On my phone, I can see the calendar under Settings > Accounts and Calendar folders, but the calendar is greyed out. So the phone know that the calendar is there, but is not downloading the events. Does anyone know how to 'activate' this? (NB I have quite a few calendars withing Google calendar. Is there an upper limit?)

Thanks

(PS Device = Blackberry Keyone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is old and you may have already found a solution but I ran into something like this today (on my BB Keyone) and solved it by simply un-checking and re-checking the relevant calendar account. Doing so caused the greyed out calendars to begin to sync to my phone.

Answer (score 1):

My "sync now" button was grayed out and it didn't sync for weeks. It turns out I had a power saver mode on and that was causing the problem. I had to turn off power saving and the "sync now" turned on and it auto-synced.